# Strategy to retrieve the current user

Tags: javascript, ajax, ember.js, ember-old-router

I'm looking for a classy strategy to retrieve the current user information with emberjs (and ember-data).

Currently, I do the following :

My API responds to `/users/me` with the current user.
In my adapter, when the retrieved object id isn't the one I'm hoping for, I add a `real_id` which is the id (the user's id in the database) and I replace the real returned id by what I'm expecting.

So when my adapter has "me" as user's id, but the server returns 1, I get the following json :

```
{"real_id": 1, "id": "me"}
```

This works. But I'm not a big fan, and I'd like to avoid as mush as possible to change the default content of the adapter.

Do you use any strategy for this ? What would you recommend ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would use a controller `App.currentUserController` for this.

```
App.CurrentUserController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    content: null,

    retrieveCurrentUser: function() {
        var controller = this;
        Ember.$.getJSON('/users/me', function(data) {
            App.store.load(App.User, data);
            var currentUser = App.store.find(data.id);
            controller.set('content', currentUser);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried that, but I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'load' of undefined`

Comment: Xavier, go to wherever you define your store, and add App.store = App.Store.create()

Answer (score -5):

```
get = Em.get
set = Em.set
App.AccountController = Em.Controller.extend

        contentBinding: '_content.firstObject'

        init: ->
            set @, "_content", App.User.find()
```

Comment: This assumes the first returned user is the current one, which might not be the best idea for an api.

Comment: you could limit this on the server

Comment: Can you explain *why* this helps.

Comment: seems obvious that /users/me should return a single record, the current user.  @ChrisF, please elaborate your question?

Comment: A good answer will explain *why* as well as explain *how*. With just the *how* you could find that the same class of mistake is made in other places. With a *why* it will educate and hopefully prevent this.

Comment: Ok, should I say, "with this you don't have to touch your adapter (as this was Damien's main concern)"? pangratz workaround makes the app make two round trips to the server ...